# flask admin url of View still accessible after setting is_accessible to False

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I would like to protect access to my Views based on flask-security roles. So, for instance, I have set up:

```
class AdminView(ModelView):    
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.has_role('admin')
```

and

```
admin.add_view(AdminView(User, db.session))
```

The logic works: when I log in with a non-admin user, I don't see the User table, when I log in with an admin user, I see it.

But...

entering the url

```
localhost/admin/user
```

still gives every user access to the user table, for both admins and non-admins. How can I use flask Admin to protect also the url against access of non-admins? (Honestly, I would have expected `def is_accessible()` to manage that in the first place.)

Comment: There is a self-contained example of handling Flask-Admin role based permissions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33653754/2800058).

Answer (score -1):

you could add a `@login_required` decorator to your view ([read here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/viewdecorators/)) & since you are using flask-security, which is built partially on top of flask-login, that decorator might already be there.

Comment: Actually that doesn't help me, since I have roles-based. The permissions, which Role can see which View are edible by the admins during runtime. That's why I need some solution within the class definition of the flask-Admin Views.

Comment: Okay, I see your problem. You could firstly always built your own route decorator. Or, check out the Flask-Principal extension: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/

Comment: Since I already got Flask-Security working, which includes Flask-Principal, I don't understand, what you want to tell me with the last sentence in your comment.