# How do I display the db models in the User view of Flask-Admin

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin, flask-security

I have created an admin panel using Flask-Admin, and created three non admin users. I want to display a database table called as Usertest inside the users section of the panel. Right now for the admin (super user part) I am able to display all the database tables. I want to display one or two tables in the user view of the admin panel, how do i go about it ?

Here is the model_views.py code

```
class MyModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        if current_user.has_role('superuser') :
            return True
        return False

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        """
        Override builtin _handle_view in order to redirect users
          when a view is not accessible.
        """
        if not self.is_accessible():
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                # permission denied
                abort(403)
            else:
                # login
                return redirect(url_for('security.login', next=request.url))

class CarUserView():
    column_display_pk = True
    form_columns = ['id', 'desc']
    column_searchable_list = ['desc']
    column_filters = ['id']
    can_create = True
    can_edit = True
    can_delete = False  # disable model deletion
    can_view_details = True
    page_size = 2  # pagination
    create_modal = True
    edit_modal = True
    can_export = True

class CarAdminView(MyModelView):
    column_display_pk = True
    form_columns = ['id', 'desc']
    column_searchable_list = ['desc']
    column_filters = ['id']
    column_editable_list = ['desc']
    can_create = True
    can_edit = True
    can_delete = True
    can_view_details = True
    page_size = 2
    create_modal = True
    edit_modal = True
    can_export = True
```

and this is the app.py code :

```
class Car(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc
class usertest(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    desc=db.Column(db.String(50))

# --------------------------------
# MODEL VIEW CLASSES
# --------------------------------
from model_views import (
    CarAdminView, CarUserView, MyModelView
)

# --------------------------------
# FLASK VIEWS / ROUTES
# --------------------------------
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
    #return redirect("/admin")

# --------------------------------
# CREATE FLASK ADMIN
# --------------------------------
admin = flask_admin.Admin(
    app,
    '',
    base_template='my_master.html',
    template_mode='bootstrap3',
)
admin.add_view(CarAdminView(Car, db.session))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(Profile, db.session))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(Username, db.session))
admin.add_view(CarUserView(usertest,db.session))
```

If i change the conditions in MyModelView such that it displays the table for both admin and non admin user all the tables are being displayed, which is not necessary. I expected it to only display the specified tables for the user view. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flask-admin is\_accessible usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646165/flask-admin-is-accessible-usage)

Comment: this is a different approach, im not sure how to implement it. I have already defined accessible function. Now i just want to display the views for a non admin user.

Comment: @pjcunningham i think this question portrays my problem more accurately : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75051017/how-can-i-prevent-the-display-of-few-views-for-a-particular-user-in-flask-admi , please help me out I have been stuck on this for many days now.